# How to uninstall multiple Xcode instances in OS X 10.9

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, uninstallation

I have multiple Xcode Apps installed in OS X 10.9.2 to check the compatibility. Now I am facing a problem when I run the app, this error occurs "iOS simulator failed to install the application". I want uninstall all Xcode completely to reinstall latest Xcode 5.1. How can I do that? Thanks.

Xcode Instances

- /Applications/Xcode.app (Xcode v5.0.2)
- ~/Apps/Xcode.app  (Xcode v4.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Appcleaner](http://appcleaner.en.softonic.com/mac)

or

Just drag and drop Xcode to trash from app folder

Comment: Thanks @Lithu T.V. Do these methods clean all related system files used by Xcode apps?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue. From the -->>

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html

- **After switching the minimum deployment target of an application from
  iOS 7.0 to a release prior to iOS 7.0, building and running the
  application may fail with the message “iOS Simulator failed to
  install the application.

### ” Go to the iOS home screen, click and hold the application icon, then tap the hovering “X” button to delete the application.

**

Another release note:

- **iOS Simulator If an iOS app is detached, relaunching the same app
  from Xcode will result in a black screen in the Simulator even though
  the new app is launched. Terminate the app in the Simulator or
  relaunch it for the second time.**

---

---

Answer (score 1):

if you have already developed project and you used xib to develop views then

X-Code > Inspector Selector Bar > Interface Builder Document > opens in > and change from Xcode Default(5.o) to Xcode 4.6 . 
[image]

Build and Run your app it will run successfully, if it won't run again then, header over to iOS Simulator - Reset Content and Settings. delete old app from simulator then Run again.